# Multiple Redux Actions in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

What is the proper convention for firing two different actions inside ComponentDidMount()? Specifically two API calls that are made when the page is loaded? I have a try/catch on all of my actions to handle errors if they occur and that then updates the state. but in my current situation one call fails, triggering error state, but other call completes right after setting state back to null. I'm trying to use axios.all() inside componentdidmount but that doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Why does a component have to handle a failed action? If you thunk action fails then why not dispatch a fail action from there. Your component only needs to dispatch the action and select the result **from state**. If you need to call thunkA and thunkB in parallel you can write a combindedThunk that does the following:  `const thunkA = () => (dispatch) => {
  return Promise;
};
const combinedThunk = () => (dispatch) =>
  Promise.all([thunkA()(dispatch), thunkB()(dispatch)]);`

Answer (score 0):

i actually figured this out. i was updating the error state back to null in other actions, which is incorrect. probably still need to create a combinedThunk but for now this solution works.